# MVC3 Model Binding Error: ...but the parameter requires a value of type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting an exception on my server at the datacenter, BUT I am not getting the error on my dev box, nor on my server in our offices.

Here is my contoller method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IndEvent[] events)
```

I have a bunch of checkboxes on my view that mvc then gives me an array of IndEvents and the checkboxes are bound to a bool.

If the user does not check any boxes, I get a full array with the bool being false.

At the datacenter when the user does not check any of the boxes, I get back a string[], not an IndEvent[].

> Message: The parameters dictionary contains an invalid entry for
>   parameter 'events' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Index(MAC.Common.WebMACTexas.Areas.IndustryEvent.Models.IndEvent[])'
>   in
>   'MAC.Common.WebMACTexas.Areas.IndustryEvent.Controllers.RegisterController'.
>   The dictionary contains a value of type 'System.String[]', but the
>   parameter requires a value of type
>   'MAC.Common.WebMACTexas.Areas.IndustryEvent.Models.IndEvent[]'.

MVC Version locally: 3.0.11209.0

MVC Version at DataCenter 3.0.11209.0

++in case you didn't read the first line of this post here it is:

I am getting an exception on my server at the datacenter, BUT I am not getting the error on my dev box, nor on my server in our offices.

Comment: Why are you passing any parameter to your index? Where is your code

Comment: Sorry, that is the [Httppost], so mvc is populating my array when the page is posted back.  The app errors our before my code is reached, note the error message of mvc giving me a string[] not a IndEvent[].

Comment: How are you accessing Index? via another class? straight from browser?

Comment: Yes, straight from the browser, this is an asp.net mvc web app.

Comment: What does the HTML in the view look like? You are probably not giving the fields correctly formatted IDs for MVC to auto-bind them to a complex object.

Comment: Please read my post.  My code works fine locally on my dev box and a test server.  The difference is it doesn't work properyly on a production server.

Answer (score 0):

There is now way u will pass a object(s) via the webrowsers. You can only pass strings your Index should look something like

```
public ActionResult Index(string somepropetry)
{

  using(var context = new SiteContext())
  {
     var events = context.IndEvents.where(e=>e.property.equal(someproperty).toList();
     return View(events)
  }

}
```

depending on how u want to filter it

Comment: and why are u trying to 
[HttpPost] index

Comment: Don't get hung up on the name of the method/view it is imaterial to this situation.  On post back the mvc framework news up an array of my objects and populates them via the modelbinding feature.  "I" am not passing objects, MVC is doing the work for me.

Comment: My point is this works fine locally on two machines, but works intermittenly on a production server, so I think it has something to do with the mvc versions, even though the version #'s are the same.